# Archlinux'es pacman + tee == unclear console IO

Tags: arch-linux, io-redirection, console, pacman

I have a small issue with capturing the `pacman`'s IO with the `tee` utility. I try this command line:

```
pacman -S group-1 group-2 | tee pacman.log
```

And there is an issue: when the pacman query which packages from the `group-1` shall it to install a list of the packages is disappeared somewhere. If I press `Enter` (ie choose "All packages"), then the list of them appeared and pacman query about packages from the `group-2`, but as earlier the list of the packages is hidden.

Comment: pacman logs everything to `/var/log/pacman/log`: what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @jasonwryan, as far as I know pacman don't log a recommended dependencies, changed config filenames etc. In anyway I could know how to do this.

Comment: If you want to print the packages in the group (that pacman displays for you to select from) use: `pacman -Sg group`.

Answer (score 2):

If pacman writes to the standard error, that will not be captured with the given pipe command.  You could redirect the standard error to follow the standard output, like this:

```
pacman -S group-1 group-2 2>&1 | tee pacman.log
```

but a less intrusive solution for interactive command-line programs is to capture the output using [`script`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html), e.g.,

```
script -c "pacman -S group-1 group-2" pacman.log
```

for Linux.  That will capture *all* characters sent to the terminal without interfering with prompts.

For specific programs, you may find specific solutions.  For instance, the [`pacman`](https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html) manual says it has a possibly useful option:

> **`-p, --print`**
>
> Only print the targets instead of performing the actual operation (sync, remove or upgrade). Use `--print-format` to specify how targets are displayed. The default format string is `"%l"`, which displays URLs with `-S`, file names with `-U`, and *pkgname-pkgver* with `-R`.

Comment: Or, you could just use the correct pacman switch... :p

Comment: The `script` works.